# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am currently implementing my first project using keras/tensorflow, and so far it works pretty good, but now I ran into an error I don't know how to solve. I googled a lot and found lots of relating questions, but none solved my issue.

Here is what I want to achieve:

I have a model for a chatbot that I trained with a dataset to provide "standard" conversations like hello, how are u and stuff. Now I want to "extend" the existing Model with a dataset that provides answers to questions related to shipping, what's in stock etc.

Here is my working/already trained model:

```
# create Sequential model
    model = Sequential()

    # add first layer with input shape dependent on size of input and "relu" activation function
    model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(len(training_data_x[0]),), activation=activations.relu))

    # add Dropout to prevent overfitting
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    # additional layer with 64 neurons
    model.add(Dense(128, activation=activations.relu))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    # Additional dense layer with num of neurons of classes & softmax activation function
    # -> adds results in output layer to "1" to get %
    model.add(Dense(len(training_data_y[0]), activation=activations.softmax))
    # print(len(training_data_y[0])) = 71
    sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    # compile the model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

    output = model.fit(np.array(training_data_x), np.array(training_data_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
    plot_model_output(output)
    model.summary()
    model.save('./MyModel_tf', save_format='tf')
```

The training data is prepared in a separate class and takes a certain json file as input.

Now I just swapped the JSON file for the one with data related to the stuff I want to add to the model and tried fitting it like this:

```
json_data = json.loads(open('data.json').read())

model = load_model('MyModel_tf')

model.fit(np.array(training_data_x), np.array(training_data_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

However when I run it I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 652), found shape=(None, 71)
```

I am assuming the data is the problem.. however it is structured exactly the same just way shorter.

Now my question(s):

1. does it make sense the way I try to implement it?
2. should I try adding the additional data in a different way?
3. Does the second dataset have to be the same length as the first one?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably coming from this line

```
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(len(training_data_x[0]),), activation=activations.relu))
```

where you define the input shape of your model based on the size of the feature dimension of `training_data_x`. Now that you have defined this very specific input shape, all data fed into your model **must** have the same feature dimension size. That is the reason for your error.

Comment: Hey @AloneTogether ! :) Thanks for your answer. 
Yeah i figured it comes from this line and I thought about the fix you suggested as well, but it sadly is not practical. 

I came up with a different solution, I just parse the 2 files into one big file and train the model with this one. It is not the best solution but enough for my use case. And it doesn't rly answer my question, so I didn't post it here. However I wanted to leave the question open for people to discuss :) Happy coding

Comment: I didnt want to delete the question, because I got a bit of hate last time I wanted to delete a "useless" question. So I figured I leave it here in case someone runs into a similar issue and this question is somewhat helpful

Comment: Oh yes I understand what you mean.